# Python: A way to detect a filetype attached to a string?

Tags: python, string, ironpython, file-extension

In IronPython 2.6*, I'm trying to build a function that "corrects" a string; I have two arguments, `FILE` and `EXTN`. The idea is for them to be concatenated as necessary later in the program, but you know some people don't read instructions and you're bound to have someone enter `"FILE.*"` as their `FILE`, which would mess everything up.

I'm looking for a way to take `FILE`, have my function detect and strip `.*` (*any* extension of any length) from `FILE` *if .* exists*; It doesn't need to be in the string, and the user will be entering the same extension into `EXTN`**, so it needs not be prepared, merely consistently stripped.

My current method has me passing `FILE` and `EXTN` separately, but it's not inconceivable to redo things to take `FILE.EXTN` and break that into `FILE` and `EXTN` if need be; I don't want to if I don't have to, though, as my program is built around the former system.

*A note regarding IronPython 2.6; I'm trying to avoid IronPython-specific codes and use as simple of ones as possible, for UNIX-WIN cross-compatibility's sake. So far, everything I've done works in Python 2.7 IDE's, but obviously will not work in Python 3.x

**A note regaring `EXTN`; I *want* users to enter the proper extension into `EXTN` too, but as we know, we can't be sure of this and so the method for stripping *.i* from `FILE` must not automatically include `EXTN` as part of it.

Here is a snippet of code that may help as a reference for what I have so far. The `FILE` and `EXTN` variables have been added, and in practice, are pulled in through a middle-man program from an XML file into the script at run-time.

```
FILE = "test"
PATH = "C:\\"
EXTN = ".txt"

def CheckCorrect_FILE(srcFile): #Check-corrects FILE
    #Meh, I got nothin'...

def CheckCorrect_PATH(srcPath): #Check-corrects PATH
    if srcPath.endswith('\\') == False:
        srcPath = srcPath + "\\"
    else:
        srcPath = srcPath
    return srcPath
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using [os.path.splitext](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext). The following will always remove an extension if one exists (and do nothing if it doesn't):

```
import os
FILE = os.path.splitext(FILE)[0]
```